# How to specify a new Workspace Extension location in a Remote machine?

Tags: visual-studio-code, remote-server

I'm having problems setting up a vscode environment on a remote machine. The ".vscode-server" folder is in my home directory (/home/ID/) which is limited to 1gb.
How do I specify a new location for the extension that I want to install in my remote machine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was in fact trivial:
In the remote server, create a symbolic link between /home and a chosen directory. When launching the ssh connection with vscode, vscode-server and all the extensions will be installed in  the chosen dir.